# Instagram comment API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

i'm wanting to run a contest on Instagram where the user enters by leaving a comment - how would I go about getting past the 150 api limit?

Any paid solutions out there? Anyway I can get the comments and add them to a spreadsheet in real time?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The Instagram comments endpoint (https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN) will only return you the most recent comments, so I would recommend setting up a cron job to request the comments for the media you are using. Every minute would probably be sufficient, but you can go faster if you think more than 150 comments will get added every minute. Since they return you the most recent comments with each request, you can cache everything if you start making requests as soon as your photo posts.